# jQuery Tab Fade

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I only need a fade effect in my tab. I tryed this: but didnt work.

code follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/Chead/8cgR7/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var $k = jQuery.noConflict()

            $k(function() {
               $k('#full-tab').tabs({
                 fx: {
                opacity:'toggle'   
                    }
                    });
                });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your jsfiddle code is unusable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#full-tab').tabs('option', 'fx', { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'fast' });
```

You have to use jquery-ui of course.